# ¿Cómo convertir un XML de CFDI a un arreglo?

Tags: php, array, xml, simplexml

Necesito convertir el XML de un CFDI a un arreglo para realizar algunas operaciones de manera sencilla y rápida.

El CFDI además contiene complementos y una Addenda que se debe incluir en el arreglo.

El ejemplo de estructura es el siguiente:

```
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv33.xsd" Version="3.3" Serie="F" Folio="1" Fecha="2020-01-31T09:05:33" FormaPago="99" NoCertificado="XXXXXXXXXXXX" CondicionesDePago="Pago en una sola excibición" SubTotal="1.25" Moneda="MXN" Total="1.45" TipoDeComprobante="I" MetodoPago="PPD" LugarExpedicion="00000" Sello="SELLO">
    <cfdi:Emisor Rfc="RFCEMISOR" Nombre="NOMBREEMISOR" RegimenFiscal="REF"/>
    <cfdi:Receptor Rfc="RFCRECEPTOR" Nombre="NOMBRERECEPTOR" UsoCFDI="USOCFDI"/>
    <cfdi:Conceptos>
        <cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="CLAVEPRODUCTOSERVICIO" Unidad="UNIDAD" Cantidad="1" ClaveUnidad="CLV" Descripcion="EJEMPLO DE CFDI" ValorUnitario="1.25" Importe="1.25">
            <cfdi:Impuestos>
                <cfdi:Traslados>
                    <cfdi:Traslado Base="1.25" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="0.2"/>
                </cfdi:Traslados>
            </cfdi:Impuestos>
        </cfdi:Concepto>
    </cfdi:Conceptos>
    <cfdi:Impuestos TotalImpuestosTrasladados="0.2">
        <cfdi:Traslados>
            <cfdi:Traslado Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="0.2"/>
        </cfdi:Traslados>
    </cfdi:Impuestos>
    <cfdi:Complemento>
        <tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/TimbreFiscalDigital/TimbreFiscalDigitalv11.xsd" Version="1.1" UUID="UUIDEJEMPLO" FechaTimbrado="2020-01-31T11:54:23" RfcProvCertif="RFCPROVCERTIF" SelloCFD="SELLOCFD"/>
    </cfdi:Complemento>
    <cfdi:Addenda>
        <ad:ADENDAS xmlns:ad="http://www.addenda.com">
            <ad:CAB VARIABLE_CUSTOM="VALOR CUSTOM">
                <ad:Conceptos>
                    <ad:LINEA LABEL="TEST" NUM_LIN="1" CONCEPTO="EJEMPLO DE CFDI" CANTIDAD="1" UNIDAD="CLV" PRECIO_UNIT="1.25" IMPORTE_LINEA="1.25" IVA="0.2" TOTAL="1.45"/>
                </ad:Conceptos>
            </ad:CAB>
        </ad:ADENDAS>
    </cfdi:Addenda>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

He intentado varias versiones con `$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);` pero no funcionan del todo o no me traen la información completa.

Lo que necesito es convertir el XML con su organización exacta a un arreglo, por ejemplo:

```
[Comprobante]
    "xmlns:cfdi" => "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" 
    "xmlns:xsi" => "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    "xsi:schemaLocation" => "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv33.xsd" 
    "Version" => "3.3" 
    "Serie" => "F" 
    "Folio" => "1" 
    "Fecha" => "2020-01-31T09:05:33" 
    "FormaPago" => "99" 
    "NoCertificado" => "XXXXXXXXXXXX" 
    "CondicionesDePago" => "Pago en una sola exhibición" 
    "SubTotal" => "1.25" 
    "Moneda" => "MXN" 
    "Total" => "1.45" 
    "TipoDeComprobante" => "I" 
    "MetodoPago" => "PPD" 
    "LugarExpedicion" => "00000" 
    "Sello" => "SELLO"
    [Emisor] 
        "Rfc" => "RFCEMISOR" 
        "Nombre" => "NOMBREEMISOR" 
        "RegimenFiscal" => "REF"
    [Receptor] 
        "Rfc" => "RFCRECEPTOR" 
        "Nombre" => "NOMBRERECEPTOR" 
        "UsoCFDI" => "USOCFDI"
    [Conceptos]
        [Concepto] 
            "ClaveProdServ" => "CLAVEPRODUCTOSERVICIO" 
            "Unidad" => "UNIDAD" 
            "Cantidad" => "1" 
            "ClaveUnidad" => "CLV" 
            "Descripcion" => "EJEMPLO DE CFDI" 
            "ValorUnitario" => "1.25" 
            "Importe" => "1.25"
            [Impuestos]
                [Traslados]
                    [Traslado] 
                        "Base" => "1.25" 
                        "Impuesto" => "002" 
                        "TipoFactor" => "Tasa" 
                        "TasaOCuota" => "0.160000" 
                        "Importe" => "0.2"
...
```

Estoy pensando en realizar una función personalizada que sea recursiva que vaya formando el arreglo y lea completo el CFDI, pero si alguien tiene algo que ya funcione, me vendría bastante bien.

Comment: ¿Conoces [esta librería](https://cfdiutils.readthedocs.io/es/stable/leer/leer-cfdi/)? Quizá puede ser útil para tu caso.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano la voy a checar!

Answer (score 1):

No encontré nada que me funcionara en internet así que programé la siguiente función que regresa un arreglo justo como lo pedí en la pregunta.

Sólo es necesario pasar a la función el string del contenido de xml:

```
/**
 * Create an array of a given xml string
 * @param string XML
 * 
 * @return array XML
 */
public function xml_to_array($xml) {
    $parser = xml_parser_create();
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);
    xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1);
    xml_parse_into_struct($parser, $xml, $tags);
    xml_parser_free($parser);

    $elements   = [];
    $stack      = [];
    $parent     = "";
    $n          = 0;
    $support    = [
        'Concepto',
        'LINEA',
    ];

    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        /* Remove prefix cfdi:, tfd:, ad:, etc from titles */
        $name   = explode(':', $tag['tag'])[1];
        $index  = $name;

        if ($index == 'Conceptos') $n = 0;

        $index = in_array($index, $support) ? $n : $index;

        if ($tag['type'] == "complete" || $tag['type'] == "open") {
            $elements[$index] = [];

            if (isset($tag['attributes'])) {
                $elements[$index] = $tag['attributes'];
            }

            if (isset($tag['value'])) {
                $elements[$index]['content'] = $tag['value'];
            }

            if ($tag['type'] == "open") {
                $stack[count($stack)] = &$elements;
                $elements = &$elements[$index];
            }
        }

        if ($tag['type'] == "close") {  // pop
            $elements = &$stack[count($stack) - 1];
            unset($stack[count($stack) - 1]);
        }

        $parent = $index;

        if ($name == 'LINEA' || $name == 'Concepto' && $tag['type'] == "open" ) $n++;
    }
```